# How to Make LBS applications in Android

Tags: android, google-maps, maps, tracking, direction

Anyone has a tutorial of making LBS applications like this? I want to make an application to determine the trajectory of the city's public transport me, but I did not find his examples everywhere, if you have please help me to develop it, thank you

### It is a concept design of my application layout

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To develop an android app which uses Google API's would be a combination of Google Maps API, Location Api, Direction API and also Places API(if you want to fetch the details of your source and destination). If you are developing this app for a special transit system in your city than you would specifically need their own set of API to populate your app data.

But if you want to develop something with free open source Google API you can first make use of the Google Play Services by first referring into your app project and then getting the API key, enabling the direction api "ON" in your developer console and writing code.

Please refer to [this](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/drawing-driving-route-directions-between-two-locations-using-google-directions-in-google-map-android-api-v2/) tutorial in order to get a better insight of the transit system app you want to develop. You can customize you app UI accordingly once you have the data coming in.

Here are the bunch of links from Google's official documentation regarding implementation of all API's.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/

https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/

Hope this would help!!